# How to count how many times a category was chosen

Tags: laravel

I wanted to know how can I count the number of times a category was chosen in laravel.

Here is what I have in my code so far

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{{url('search?$what=Financial Services')}}">Financial Services()</a></li>

<li><a href="{{url('search?$what=Beauty & Personal Care')}}">Beauty & Personal Care()</a></li>

<li><a href="{{url('search?$what=Health&Medical')}}">Health & Medical()</a></li>
<li><a href="{{url('search?$what=Fitness&WellnessServices')}}">Fitness & Wellness Services()</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the piece of code you've provided, I'm assuming that you want it to count each time someone clicks the category. For this, the best method I could think of is adding a `field` within the `categories` table which is updated every time someone clicks a link.

Do remember to **lock** your database using laravel's `lockForUpdate()` method (read more about that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#pessimistic-locking)) when reading / writing to this field, since otherwise multiple people could read the same even though one of them should've read the updated value.

But basically here's what I'd do:

**CategoryController**:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
   ...validation code

   //Find the category you want
   $category = Category::where('name', $request->only(['what']))->first();

   //Add one to this category's click count
   $category->update([
     'clicks' => $category->clicks + 1
   ]);

  ...followup code / redirect
}
```